# Yii2 ActiveQuery disambiguation

Tags: yii2

I have a policy table and a policy_chapter table. I want to modify my PolicyQuery so that it will only display policies from chapters that belong to that client. Here's my code inside PolicyQuery which extends ActiveQuery:

```
public function one($db = null)
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('Admin')) return parent::one($db);
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('PolicyUser')) {
        $this->joinWith('chapter')->andWhere(['policy_chapter.client_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->client_id]);
        return parent::one($db);
    }
}
```

If the user has Admin access then he can look at any policy. If he has PolicyUser access, then it will make sure he can't get to a policy in another client's chapters. But I get this error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous The SQL being executed was: SELECT `policy`.* FROM `policy` LEFT JOIN `policy_chapter` ON `policy`.`chapter_id` = `policy_chapter`.`id` WHERE (`id`='280') AND (`policy_chapter`.`client_id`=1)

It fails because it is search on id and both the policy and the policy_chapter table have an id field. I cannot figure out how to disambiguate the id.

Comment: Post expression that use one() function. It seems that you call previously find() method with where condition on 'id' field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the findModel method in the policy controller. I replaced the `Policy::findOne($id)` call with `Policy::find()->where('policy.id = :id',[':id'=>$id])->one()`

That disambiguated the policy id.

Answer (score 0):

modify your query to this:

```
public function one($db = null)
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('Admin')) return parent::one($db);
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('PolicyUser')) {
        $this->joinWith('chapter as cha')->alias('t')->andWhere(['policy_chapter.client_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->client_id]);
        return parent::one($db);
    }
}
```

then you can use `cha.id` reference to `policy_chapter` table and `t.id` reference to `policy` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
public function one($db = null)
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('Admin')) return parent::one($db);
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('PolicyUser')) {
        $sql = $this->joinWith('chapter')->andWhere(['policy_chapter.client_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->client_id])->andWhere(['policy.id' => $this->id])->createCommand()->getRawSql();

       $model = Policy::findBySql($sql)->one();

       return $model;
    }
}
```